# Can Windows Terminal be used without Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, windows-terminal

Now that Windows Terminal can be downloaded as a Zip file containing all components directly from [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/download/v1.18.2822.0/Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.18.2822.0_x64.zip), rather than as MS Store "app", I thought I'd try it on Windows 10 (22H2, build 19045.3570).

It ran, and settings can be changed by mouse, *but it accepts no keyboard input unless *Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service* (*TabletInputService*) is enabled.*

There are *many* sites showing how to enable TabletInputService, but for a number of reasons, including login issues on one PC, I prefer *not* to use that Service, and have disabled it. Though I've hundreds of applications installed, this is the *first and only time* I've found one depending on that Service.

Is there any way to use Windows Terminal *without* enabling *TabletInputService*? [This is more to learn about a new feature than a necessary tool, since CMD and PowerShell work without Terminal.]

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. This has been addressed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/pull/8095) and a warning incorporated when using the Terminal in version 1.4.3141.0 as indicated [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.4.3141.0#:~:text=We%20will%20now%20warn%20you%20if%20the%20keyboard%20service%20is%20disabled%20(%238095)%2C%20because%20that%20makes%20it%20impossible%20to%20type%20into%20Terminal).

Comment: The full name of the service is ""Touch, **Keyboard** and Handwriting Panel Service".

Comment: @harrymc, 1. There's no comma in the name. 2. The full name, *and* the name of the actual SVC (TabletInputService), were copied directly from Services.msc... if you see an error, please let me know so it can be fixed.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio, yes, that was stated in the question... I am asking if there is a *workaround*.

Comment: You're then in uncharted waters. In this [answer](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/8045#issuecomment-992971544) one answer is "Honestly, we don't really know. All we know is that XAML Islands (the tech stack that's powering the Terminal) *does*. Might be something weird about the way that input gets shuttled between a Win32 message loop and a CoreInputSite message pump. It might be something that magically gets fixed by moving off islands to WinUI 3, it might not (that's looking less possible by the day regardless)." ...

Comment: ... In another [answer](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/8130#issuecomment-1213443891) this same developer called the service "a critical OS service".

Comment: Then, thanks, @harrymc; it looks as if there *is no workaround*, and due to the login issue mentioned above, i will not test further. It is a bit moot, since Win10 is about EOL.

Comment: It might be easier to search for a solution to the login problem.